# Qt : How to generate .h and .cpp from a .ui file - Vim and Qt is it practical?

Tags: c++, qt, vim

I have been using `Qt` for a while in `Windows` with `Visual Studio` on Windows using the `Qt  Addin`.
For creating forms I would use `Qt Designer` and when I would save the form which I would get a `*.ui` file, a `*.cpp` file and a `*.h` file. Now on `GNU/Linux` I plan to use `Vim` for development. I could create `Qt` based programs using `Vim` however I would like to design forms using `Qt Designer` and integrate the saved `*.ui` file into my project and use those forms. How can I use the `*.ui` designed form in my `C++` project?

Comment: I think you should post your update as a new question. And since the answers helped you, please mark one as accepted.

Comment: Are you by chance using qmake or CMake as build system? Then, it should not be a vim problem since the cpp and h files should be auto-generated after the first build.

Comment: @Adri C.S Ill post the update as a new question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `uic` to compile the .ui file would do. Some instruction [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/uic.html). You can also use qtcreator on linux, which includes the vim editing mode plugin.

Comment: Luckily, QtCreator's vim editing mode also works fine on Windows :-)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK if you add all your files to your `*.pro` project file, `qmake` it and compile the result with `cl` everything should work fine. Just for the task of processing `*.ui` files you can use the [Qt UI Compiler](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/uic.html).

From experience I would say that trying to use `Vim` this way is a real challenge and I wish you good luck with that. In case you change your mind maybe you should know that `Qt Creator` has a `Vim` mode called [FakeVim](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.5/creator-editor-fakevim.html), maybe you should take a look at that as well.

**Update:**

You don't *create a header file that inherits from the generated header*, you create a class that inherits from or uses the generated class. Considering that, I would really recommend you use `Qt Creator` or, if you really want `Vim`, use `FakeVim`. Using `Vim` in this situation is hard and if you're not an advanced, or at least intermediate `Vim` user you will find it very painful. Vim is powerful but hard to setup for beginners. You will need plug-ins for autocomplete, project tree or neat jumps from header to source just to name a few and setting these up is not very user friendly/straight forward.

My advice: Use `Qt Creator` or `FakeVim`.

Comment: I have my vim plugins setup ready. I think I would be ok with Vim. My question is if its practical ? Do other developers use the pure vim approach ? Furthermore would I need to create a class that inherits from the generated class ?

Comment: @MistyD If you are a pro Vim user, yes, it is practical. If not, it is not practical. Yes, you need to create a class that inherits from the generated class and call `setupUi` on it in order to initialize the UI. This is what Qt does by default and this is the way it has to be done: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-a-ui-file.html