# Adding a QMainWindow class in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I am super new to Qt programming and Visual Studio, so this question is gonna sound super lame. But please bear with me and kindly guide me through. I am creating a login page and after validation, I take the user to the home page. When I added a new QMainWindow thorough the solution explorer, I was able to create only the '*.ui' file. and not the '.h' or '.cpp' files. So I deleted the '.ui' file and created a Qt class. It turns out that I can create only a QWidgets class, but I need a toolbar and a status bar, which I can't create in the 'QWidget.ui'. Please can someone help me create a 'QMainWindow.ui' with all the '*.h' and '*.cpp' files?
I am adding the screenshot of my problem...

[image: Screenshot of the add new class]

[image: Screentshot of the add new file]

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods to create .h and .cpp.

1.In `qt installation package->qbase->bin`, there is a uic.exe to create .h and .cpp corresponding to ui. You could open `cmd` and `cd path of bin`, then enter `uic XXX.ui -o XXX.h` and `uic XXX.ui -o XXX.cp`.

2. In VS, right-click `.ui file -> compile`.

If you want to create .h and .cpp at the beginning, you could use QTCreator.

Comment: Hi there Barrnet Chou, I found uic.exe at "C:\QtVs\5.15.0\msvc2019_64\bin". Running the executable opened cmd without the terminal to enter commands and had no reaction on entering commands. Running the command that you had suggested in cmd at the location of uic.exe said that XXX.ui was missing and running it at the location of my project said that 'uic was not part of a batch file'. Compiling XXX.ui had no effect. Thanks for your time though.

Comment: May I ask if you `cd .../bin`, just like `cd Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\mingw482_32\bin` ?

Comment: I did "cd C:\QtVs\5.15.0\msvc2019_64\bin".

Comment: You could refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26989441/qt-how-to-generate-h-and-cpp-from-a-ui-file-vim-and-qt-is-it-practical).